# how do i print a value stored in treemap if the the 2 values that are being compared have the same values?

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

If i input the following:

```
student #1
id number: 1
name: aaa
course: cs

student#2
id number: 1
name: aaa
course: cs
```

it should be prompted by treemap to sort by id number.
Then, it should print like this:

```
student   id number   course
aaa       1           cs
aaa       1           cs
```

but in my case, it looked like this:

```
student   id number   course
aaa       1           cs
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class studentreport {
    static Scanner j = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> studentnumberA = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> studentnameA = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> courseA = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Double> prelimA = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<Double> midtermA = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<Double> finalsA = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<Double> sumA = new ArrayList<Double>();

        double prelim, midterm, finals;
        String menu, menu2;
        String transaction = null, transaction2 = null, transaction3 = null;
        String studentname = null, course = null, studentnumber = null;

        do {
            System.out.print("\t\t\tDi Natuto University \n\t\t\t    " +
                    "Pililla,Rizal \n\n\t\t\t" +
                    "Main Menu \n\t\tSM\tStudent Maintenance" +
                    "\n\t\tSR\tStudent Report \n\t\tSGR\t" +
                    "Student Grade Report \n\t\tX\tExit \n\n\t\tProcess? ");
            menu = j.nextLine();
            if (menu.equals("x") || menu.equals("X")) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (menu.equals("SM") || menu.equals("sm")) {
                do {
                    System.out.print("Student Number: ");
                    studentnumber = j.nextLine();
                    studentnumberA.add(studentnumber);

                    System.out.print("Student Name: ");
                    studentname = j.nextLine();
                    studentnameA.add(studentname);

                    System.out.print("Course : ");
                    course = j.nextLine();
                    courseA.add(course);

                    System.out.print("Prelim Grade: ");
                    prelim = j.nextDouble();
                    prelimA.add(prelim);

                    System.out.print("Midterm Grade: ");
                    midterm = j.nextDouble();
                    midtermA.add(midterm);

                    System.out.print("Finals Grade: ");
                    finals = j.nextDouble();
                    finalsA.add(finals);
                    j.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Continue? (Y/N): ");
                    transaction = a.nextLine();

                } while (transaction.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
            }

            if (menu.equalsIgnoreCase("sr")) {
                do {
                    System.out
                    .println("\t\t\tDi Natuto University \n\t\t\t" +
                            "Pililla,Rizal \n\n\t\t\tStudent Summary Report" +
                            "\n\n\t\t\tSNo\tStudent no." +
                            "\n\t\t\tSna\tStudent Name \n\t\t\tCo\tCourse" +
                            "\n\t\t\tX\tExit \n\n\t\tProcess? ");
                    menu2 = j.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    if (menu2.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                    if (menu2.equalsIgnoreCase("sno")) {

                        String[] array = studentnumberA
                                .toArray(new String[studentnumberA.size()]);
                        String[] array2 = studentnameA
                                .toArray(new String[studentnameA.size()]);
                        String[] array3 = courseA.toArray(new String[courseA
                                                                     .size()]);
                        String[][] storeAllArray = { array, array2, array3 };
                        TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
                        TreeMap<String, String> map2 = new TreeMap<String, String>();

                        System.out
                        .println("\t\t\t\tDi Natuto University \n\t\t\t\t" +
                                "Pililla,Rizal \n\n\t\t\t\t" +
                                "Student Summary Report \n\n\t\t\tStudent no."
                                + "Student Name\t\tCourse ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            map2.put(array[i], array3[i]);
                            map.put(array[i], array2[i]);

                        }
                        for (String key : map.keySet())
                            System.out.println("\t\t\t" + key + "\t\t "
                                    + map.get(key) + "\t\t\t" + map2.get(key));
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }
                    if (menu2.equalsIgnoreCase("sna")) {
                        String[] array = studentnumberA
                                .toArray(new String[studentnumberA.size()]);
                        String[] array2 = studentnameA
                                .toArray(new String[studentnameA.size()]);
                        String[] array3 = courseA.toArray(new String[courseA
                                                                     .size()]);
                        String[][][] storeAllArray = { { array }, { array2 },
                                { array3 } };
                        TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
                        TreeMap<String, String> map2 = new TreeMap<String, String>();

                        System.out
                        .println("\t\t\t\tDi Natuto University \n\t\t\t\t" +
                                "Pililla,Rizal \n\n\t\t\t\t" +
                                "Student Summary Report \n\n\t\t\tStudent no."
                                + "   Student Name" + "\tCourse ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            map2.put(array2[i], array3[i]);
                            map.put(array2[i], array[i]);

                        }
                        for (String key : map.keySet())
                            System.out.println("\t\t\t" + map.get(key)
                                    + "\t\t " + key + "\t\t" + map2.get(key));
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }
                    if (menu2.equalsIgnoreCase("co")) {
                        String[] array = studentnumberA
                                .toArray(new String[studentnumberA.size()]);
                        String[] array2 = studentnameA
                                .toArray(new String[studentnameA.size()]);
                        String[] array3 = courseA.toArray(new String[courseA
                                                                     .size()]);
                        TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
                        TreeMap<String, String> map2 = new TreeMap<String, String>();

                        System.out
                        .println("\t\t\t\tDi Natuto University \n\t\t\t\t" +
                                "Pililla,Rizal \n\n\t\t\t\t" +
                                "Student Summary Report \n\n\t\t\tStudent no."
                                + "   Student Name" + "\tCourse ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            map2.put(array3[i], array2[i]);
                            map.put(array3[i], array[i]);

                        }
                        for (String key : map.keySet())
                            System.out.println("\t\t\t" + map.get(key)
                                    + "\t\t " + map2.get(key) + "\t\t" + key);
                        System.out.println("\n");

                    }

                    System.out.print("Continue? (Y/N)");
                    transaction2 = j.nextLine();
                } while (transaction2.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
            }
            if (menu.equalsIgnoreCase("sgr")) {

                String[] array = studentnumberA
                        .toArray(new String[studentnumberA.size()]);
                String[] array2 = studentnameA.toArray(new String[studentnameA
                                                                  .size()]);
                String[] array3 = courseA.toArray(new String[courseA.size()]);
                Double[] array4 = prelimA.toArray(new Double[prelimA.size()]);
                Double[] array5 = midtermA.toArray(new Double[midtermA.size()]);
                Double[] array6 = finalsA.toArray(new Double[finalsA.size()]);
                Double[] array7 = sumA.toArray(new Double[sumA.size()]);
                String[][] storeAllArray = { array, array2, array3 };
                TreeMap<Double, String> map = new TreeMap<Double, String>();
                TreeMap<Double, String> map2 = new TreeMap<Double, String>();
                TreeMap<Double, String> map3 = new TreeMap<Double, String>();

                System.out
                .println("\t\t\t\tDi Natuto University \n\t\t\t\t" +
                        "Pililla,Rizal \n\n\t\t\t\t" +
                        "Student Grade Report \n\n\t\t\tStudent no."
                        + "   Student Name"
                        + "\tCourse"
                        + "\t\t\tAverage");

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    double sum = (array4[i] + array5[i] + array6[i]) / 3;
                    sumA.add(sum);
                    map.put(array7[i], array[i]);
                    map2.put(array7[i], array2[i]);
                    map3.put(array7[i], array3[i]);

                }
                for (Double key : map.keySet())
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t" + map.get(key) + "\t\t "
                            + map2.get(key) + "\t\t" + map2.get(key) + "\t\t"
                            + key);

                System.out
                .print("\n\n\t\t\tM\t\tMain Menu\n\t\t\tX\t\tExit\nChoice: ");
                transaction3 = j.nextLine();

                if (transaction3.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    System.out
                    .print("\t\t\t\tDi Natuto University \n\t\t\t\t" +
                            "Pililla,Rizal \n\n\t\t\t\t" +
                            "Thank you for using Di Natuto Grading System...");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        } while (transaction.equalsIgnoreCase("N")
                || transaction2.equalsIgnoreCase("N")
                || transaction3.equalsIgnoreCase("M"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Small suggestion for code efficiency would be to instead of having `studentnumber = j.nextLine();
          studentnumberA.add(studentnumber);`   and instead having            
          `studentnumberA.add(j.nextLine());`

Comment: Careful with your for() loops; you have a few places where there's no braces and the indentation is misleading. The whole thing is pretty badly indented which makes reading it more difficult; please use a java IDE.

Comment: As an aside, if you name your give meaningful names to your variables (`Scanner j` & `Scanner a` ?) and avoid numbers in the name (`menu` & `menu2`) the code is much more readable.

Comment: @Sully Brooks i have already followed your suggestion. thanks btw :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I have looked at and tested, it seems that the issue is non-existent. You are running into this problem because you are trying to print a duplicate entry. With identical keys, the `TreeMap` assumes that it doesn't need to be printed anymore.

Because you are trying to store two identical keys in a TreeMap, it won't work the way you seem to want it to.

**Suggestion to fix it:**
You could try switching the order of which you store keys and values. You could store them so that the student name is the key and their student number is the value (or any other different combination that will avoid duplicate keys).

**Code Suggestions:**
I noticed that your code is very long and has a few lines that could be shortened up.

For one:

```
        studentnumber=j.nextLine();
        studentnumberA.add(studentnumber);
```

this could be shortened up to simply `studentnumberA.add(j.nextLine());`

Along with all of the other variables in your menu code.

If you still don't understand what the problem is, feel free to ask. I, along with many others would love to help you.

Comment: can you do it for me? or give me an example of it so that i can clearly understand it? im new in java and i wanna learn some new codes that isn't being taught in our school

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is that TreeMap (as every map) cannot have duplicated values for keys. When you do:

```
map.put("aaa", "Something");
map.put("aaa", "Another stuff");
```

You are basically overwriting your first "assignment" with the second one. So it is a bad idea.

I understand your are using `TreeMap` as a way to sort your results, so allow me to make a suggestion. What if you define your object `Student` which holds name, id and course properties (assuming those are properties of what you define as an student in your model). Then just make such object implement the `Comparable` interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) defining your criteria of sorting.

After reading or the data that belongs to an student from your `Scanner` you just create an instance of Student wrapping all those and you add them not to a `TreeMap` but to any `SortedSet` (like `TreeSet`).

After that you just have to iterate over your set and print each student data.

Comment: i don't know how to do it. im a newbie in java. maybe if u could do it for me it'll be of big help for a beginner like me :)

Comment: "doing it for you" is no way to help a beginner. Have a go & ask a specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: Exactly. If you can come up with specific questions like "how can I create an object Student?", "Why are you suggesting it to be Comparable?" or even "Whats an object in java and how I can define one?" it will be simpler for us to answer. Otherwise it will look like us doing your homework and that's not helpful.

Comment: @caludio fernandez how can you say that you're doing my homework if i did it already but unfortunately there's this 1 problem left. please stop making me look lazy here, because i'm doing everything i can to solve my problem. if u can't help and if u feel like i'm using you just don't say something negative about what i say.

Answer (score 0):

Student "id number" is the unique key to your Treemap; adding a duplicate replaces the previous value.

This occurs here:

```
map2.put(array[i], array3[i]);
```

If you want two students with the same ID you need to store them with a different unique key.

Comment: i have tried what you said. stored the value of id number into another new array and then inserted it in treemap. but the problem is still there. maybe what i did was wrong in prior to what you said. if u could just edit my program and send it to me id appreciate it much. thanks :D

Comment: i have tried it like this: 
map2.put(array1[i], array3[i]);
map.put(array[i], array2[i]);

array=id num
array1= id num(new array as you said)

Comment: Asking people to "do it for you" (which you've asked for exactly in 3 comments) isn't sending a good message. Please show that you have put some effort into cleaning up your code first.

Comment: I'd recommend you either start again building around a new Student class, or split your code into methods no more than 20 lines each, then go from there.

Comment: yes i am putting some effort. not that i just want others to do it for me, but because i can't clearly understand what people are trying to teach. but if someone can fix my problem for me. i sure will appreciate it and it will be a great contribution for a newbie like me in java. :)

Comment: im not just sitting here waiting for someone to do it for me, i'm just putting my hope here while im trying to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of bugs in this code. Try breaking it into smaller pieces and extracting duplicated code into common methods.

E.g here you've been copy-paste happy and are printing map2.get(key) twice instead of (presumably) the contents of map3 for that key:

```
System.out.println("\t\t\t"+map.get(key)+ "\t\t "+map2.get(key)+"\t\t"+map2.get(key)+"\t\t"+key);
```

The masses of `\t` make this line unreadable, and its meaning unclear. Consider instead how it would look if you extracted a `printStudent` method:

```
public static void printStudent(String id, String name, String course, int key) {
   System.out.println("\t\t\t"+ id + "\t\t "+ name +"\t\t"+ course +"\t\t" + key);
}
```

The line in main now appears as:

```
printStudent(map.get(key), map2.get(key), map2.get(key), key);
```

which hopefully makes it a little easier to see what the line is doing and to spot the copy-paste error.